# Relacionamento entre tabelas causa o erro: "Unknown column 'Setores.name' in 'where clause'"

Tags: php, cakephp-3

Eu tenho um relacionamento entre 2 `models`: `Ramais` e `Setores`, e imprimo os dados dos 2 na tela, mas eu preciso fazer funcionar um campo de Pesquisa, mas eu só consegui fazer pesquisar os dados da tabela dos `Ramais`, como nome e ramal, os dados dos `Setores` eu não consigo puxar do banco, alguém tem alguma dica do que estou fazendo errado ?

```
public function search()
{
    $ramais = $this->paginate($this->Ramais);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $search = null;
        if (isset($this->request->data['search'])) {
            $search = $this->request->data['search'];
        }

        $ramal = $this->Ramais->find('all',
            [
                'contain' => ['Setores'],

                'conditions'=>['OR'=>
                    [
                        'Ramais.name LIKE'=>'%'.$search.'%',
                        'Ramais.ramal LIKE'=>'%'.$search.'%',
                        'Setores.name LIKE'=>'%'.$search.'%'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );

        //debug($ramal); exit();

        $this->set(compact('ramais', 'ramal', 'setor'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['ramais'], ['setor']);
        $this->render('index');

    }
}
```

Ele traz o seguinte **erro**:

> `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Setores.name' in 'where clause'`

Comment: você configurou a classe `Ramais` com a relação ?

Comment: Boa tarde, sim eu relacionei dessa forma. 

$this->belongsToMany('Setores', [
            'foreignKey' => 'ramai_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'setore_id',
            'joinTable' => 'ramais_setores'
        ]);

Comment: A coluna `name` existe mesmo na tabela `Setores`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para você fazer um filtro a partir de uma segunda tabela você precisa utilizar o matching().

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data

O matching irá fazer o inner join de sua tabela acompanhado de uma condição. 
Cuidado para não se confundir com a função innerJoinWith(). Ela possibilita realizar o filtro contudo não te retorna os valores que deseja imprimir, ou seja, não adiciona os campos da segunda tabela no select.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta. Eu dei uma pesquisada esses dias nessa função matching(), e deu certo eu acabei esquecendo de finalizar minha pergunta aqui. No caso ficou assim:

->contain(['Setores'])
->matching('Setores');